# can u fix my js dynamic loading doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, api

i want to add a js script in another js page but  its does'nt work i don't know i want to add jquery but still undifiend :
**plugins.js :**

```
var jquery = document.createElement("script");

jquery.type = "text/javascript";
jquery.src = "assets/vendor/js/jquery.min.js";

document.body.appendChild(jquery);
```

**index.html :**

```
<body>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the bug :
**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at main.js:1**

Comment: Can you add `main.js` file here?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  alert('hello')  
})

Comment: You have not included the jquery library. I have posted my answer. Accept the same if it solves your issue :)

Comment: i want use the script to add jquery lib thats what i wanna do

Comment: i know its solve problem but i wanna add it dynamicly !

Comment: Just what you asked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605800/16509983

Answer (score 0):

If the ask is to load the scripts dynamically, you can load the `jquery` library via the `plugins.js` followed by the `main.js` file this way. This will work and work as intended.

```
<body>
    <script>
        (function () {
            function loadScript(url, afterLoad) {
                var script = document.createElement("script")
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.onload = function () {
                    afterLoad();
                };
                script.src = url;
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
            }
            loadScript('./assets/js/plugins.js', function () {
                console.log('jquery has been added to DOM');
                loadScript('./assets/js/main.js', function () {
                    console.log('jquery use now allowed');
                });
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```